# Как создать авторегистратор?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
 !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeLink() {
         document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = Math.random;

       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p><span id="login">Логин</span>
     <button type="button" onclick="changeLink()">Изменить логин</button><p>

  </body>
</html>
```

А как сделать так, чтобы я смог создать рандомный логин из чисел и букв, нажимая на кнопку, я много примеров перепробовал- всё бестолку...

Comment: всмысле вы хотите нажать на `кнопку` и чтобы вам выдало рандомную строку ??

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц да, так и есть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1349404/

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я гуглил авторегистратор на js)

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var changeLogin = document.getElementById("changeLogin");
  changeLogin.onclick = showCoords;
}

function showCoords(eventObj) {
  var login = document.getElementById("login");
  var math = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);

  login.innerHTML = math;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="changeLogin"></button>
<p id="login">Click on button</p>
```